# Fermat's procedure finding tangents

Tags: geometry, tangent-line

I am studying Fermat's procedure for finding tangent lines to curves.
In this example he writes:

"Let us consider, for example, the parabola BDN [Fig. 70.2] with vertex D and diameter DC; B is a point on it at which the line BE is to be drawn tangent to the parabola and intersecting the diameter at E.
We choose on the segment BE a point O at which we drwa the ordinate OI; also we construct the ordinate BC of the point B.

We have then: **CD/DI > BC^2/OI^2**, since the point O is exterior to the parabola."

Using that inequality he manages to show a way to express the tangent based on BC and CD.
However, I fail to see where that inequality comes from or why we know it applies.

Can anyone explain the inequality to me?
[image]

Comment: Let $IO$ intersect the parabola at $P$. Then $CD : ID = BC^2 : PI^2$ (this is the pre-algebra way of saying $y=ax^2$). So increasing $IP$ to $OP$ decreases the RHS.

Comment: Can you explain further how  CD:ID=BC^2:PI^22 and y=ax^2 are related?
I don't see how in practice they are meant to tell the same.

Comment: If you take $y$ horizontally, starting from $D$, and $x$ vertically from $CD$, then $\frac{y_1}{y_2}=\frac{x_1^2}{x_2^2}$. In classical times, a length $y$ could not be equated or compared with an 'area' $x^2$, only their ratios made sense.

Comment: Do we know that the horizontal line is the parabola's axis of symmetry?

Comment: It's given that $CD$ is the diameter of the conic, and the ordinates are with respect to it (not necessarily perpendicular). Then the relation $y=ax^2$ still holds, where $y$ is along the diameter, and $x$ along the ordinates.

Comment: How can the ordinates not be perpendicular to the diamter?
A diameter is always parallel to the axis og symmetry, right?

Comment: The diameter is parallel to the axis of symmetry. But the ordinates, by definition, are the chords parallel to the tangent touching the vertex of this diameter. A change of coordinates can take a parabola, with any diameter and its ordinates, to the standard parabola $y=ax^2$.